# Laravel 5 Fetching XML The Right Way

Tags: xml, laravel-5

I'm fairly new to Laravel and I'm currently building a site of mine for fun using Laravel 5. As of now I'm only using views and routes. The home.blade.php view fetches an xml feed using simplexml_load_file(). I realize there is probably a better way to do this using a controller, but I can't seem to find any examples out there. Could someone provide an example of the correct way to fetch an XML file in the controller, and pass this response to the view? Or is there an even better solution out there? Thank you.